# Issue with Clay Strips - Subtracting?

Tags: sculpting

I'm new to Blender (using 2.91) and have been playing around with the sculpting.  I am having an issue with the clay strips brush.  When I use it on the front, it seems to be subtracting from the back.  I've tried to include two images to show what I'm talking about.  I've checked the normals and everything seems to be fine there but my knowledge is very limited.  What is going on?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Front of the ears - build up on the front]

[image: Back of the ears - subtracted bit matches the build up on front]

Comment: That's how it works, similar to draw brush I believe. Inflate brush won't make any problem (correct me if I'm wrong?)

Comment: Oh, and I believe it will only occur if two (connecting) faces located near each other, maybe add a cube, subdivide it and see if same thing happened.

Comment: The draw and inflate brush do what I expect on there.  I made a cube, subdivided it, and when I used the clay strips I didn't get the same issue as above.